# Using the term "hog" metaphorically

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, idioms

When a basketball or soccer player tries to do everything alone and avoids passing the ball to their teammates, we normally call them a "hog".
I am going to be a little creative and expand the term to someone who does not contribute in a team activity when they are suppose to participate.

My question is whether it is possible and a normal thing to do in English?

**Example:**

> Hey Kevin, we're all here to do something together as a team.
> I know you well and I'm quite sure that all you doings are for the team good. You've always done your tasks in the best way possible, but you might know that when you fulfill a part and don't let others know about it as an already completed part, they'll certainly waste the same time and energy as you spent on doing that which will lead to weakening the team's performance and functionality in the short run. As the head of this team, I expect you to be a team player and stop being such a **hog**.

Does this usage sound idiomatic to you?
If no, then I would appreciate if you could provide me with any better option.

Answer (score 3):

**Hog** is very specifically about keeping something to yourself and not letting other people have or use it, so it does not really work here.  [If you search Google for "stop hogging the"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stop%20hogging%20the%22), you find things like *PC, bed, broadband, bathroom, TV*, etc.  [In sports, being a "ball hog", or saying that someone is "hogging the ball"](https://sportsaspire.com/how-to-handle-ball-hogs) means that the player doesn't want to let anyone else touch the ball.

But in this case, the person is not keeping all of the work for themselves, they're just not telling anyone about what they're doing.  Also, calling someone a hog is very rude; I would never use this in a formal communication at work, and it doesn't fit with the tone of the rest of your writing.

I can't think of another specific idiom to use, and exact writing advice is off-topic here anyway, but you should probably just explain what behaviors you want them to show and not show.